# The linker does not report a multiple variable error - what can be the reason?

Tags: c++, linker, clang

A student of mine has C++ files similar to the following (only relevant code shown):

A.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, double>> rates;
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "A.hpp"
```

C.cpp:

```
#include "A.hpp"
int main() {}
```

I compile it in the following way:

```
clang++-9 -std=c++2a B.cpp C.cpp
```

and get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/Test-5e4305.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `rates[abi:cxx11]'; /tmp/NumberWithUnits-159887.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, my student does exactly the same thing, with exactly the same files and compilation command, and gets no errors - the code compiles and runs.

How can this be? Is there maybe a global flag that tells ld to report / not report such errors?

Note: both of us run on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The student is doing something that is (possibly slightly) different than you describe.  For example, the header file might be marking `rates` as `extern`, and then defining it in a source (.cpp) file (exactly once in the project).   Possibly the definition of `rates` is in an anonymous (unnamed) namespace so `rates` is local to every object file that refers to it (and not shared between functions if they are in different source files).

Comment: @Peter but I took the student's source files

Comment: Are the header files not guarded?

Comment: @sweenish Do you mean by "#pragma once"? Yes, they are guarded, but I removed this line since it is not relevant for the question - the header is only included once in each cpp file.

Comment: It's very relevant, since it's a common error found on this site.

Comment: @sweenish OK. But in this particular question, the results are the same with or without #pragma once.

Comment: Voting to close as I can't reproduce. I.E., I get the linker error, which I would expect for a global variable that's not declared `extern` and included all around the code. My attempt was in a Fedora 34 instance of WSL using LLVM 12.